# Mongoid queries not returning anything on new model fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a Rails application where I am trying to iterate over each object in a Model class depending on whether the object has been archived or not.

```
class Model
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :example_id, type: Integer
  field :archived, type: Boolean, default: false

  def archive_all
    Model.all.where(archived: false).each do |m|
      m.archive!
    end
  end

end
```

However, the where clause isn't returning anything.  When I go into the console and enter these lines, here is what I get:

```
Model.where(example_id: 3).count   #=> 23
Model.where(archived: false).count #=> 0
Model.all.map(&:archived) #=> [false, false, false, ...]
```

I have other where clauses throughout the application and they seem to work fine.  If it makes any difference, the 'archived' field is one that I just recently added.

What is happening here?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say:

```
Model.where(archived: false)
```

you're looking for documents in MongoDB the `archived` field is exactly `false`. If you just added your `archived` field then none of the documents in your database will have that field (and no, the `:default` doesn't matter) so there won't be any with `archived: false`.  You're probably better off looking for documents where `archived` is not `true`:

```
Model.where(:archived.ne => true).each(&:archive!)
```

You might want to add a validation on `archived` to ensure that it is always `true` or `false` and that every document has that field.